# Flutter - StreamBuilder builder function runs when navigator pops

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I have a widget called `RootContainer` which receives a `Widget child` and wrap it inside a `StreamBuilder`:

```
class RootContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  RootContainer({this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<OverlayAlert>(
      stream: ApiService.ThrottledException.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => showAlert(context, snapshot));
        }

        return this.child;
      },
    );
  }

  void showAlert(BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    print("showing dialog");
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => OverlayAlertDialog(snapshot),
    );
  }
```

When an error occurs, I add a new value to the stream `ApiService.exception.stream` which triggers the StreamBuilder builder and then it opens a dialog.

This is the current widget tree:

[image]

The problem starts when I want to pop the navigator, the `StreamBuilder.builder` builds again!

1. I thought it may happen because the `RootContainer` is being rebuilt, but placing a `print` before the `StreamBuilder` has resulted in just one print.
2. I tried to `.listen` to the stream, and the stream didn't fire when I popped the navigator so I can confirm that there's nothing wrong with `ApiService.ThrottledException.stream`.
3. The snapshot when the navigator is popped is equal (the data) to the last emission.

You can see in the following demo that whenever I press the back button the dialog pops up again:

[image]

What could cause the `StreamBuilder` to rebuild itself when I press on the back button?

Comment: Any luck with your question? I have posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56835372/flutter-stream-builder-triggered-when-navigator-pop-or-push-is-called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change `RootContainer` to extend `StatefulWidget` instead of `StatelessWidget`.

I have no idea what's happening behind the scene, but it works! Any explanation would be nice.